# How to send single quotes in a array as parameter , As i am calling a api using alamofire?

Tags: ios, swift, api, alamofire

I have to call a api to get a functionality done. In that I have to send a array as a parameter which consists single quotes. But i tried adding a single quote in that , but i am failing miserably getting nil value.

I tried removing the backslash which automatically gets created while trying to send single quotes.

```
{
    "buyerId":"ananth",
    "state":"California",
    "mobile_no":"5896235966",
    "permissionType":"3",
    "communityNoArray":"['1441','1643']",
    "community_name":"abrakasdabrama"
}
```

Comment: Add more details about your code, like your api calling, etc.

Comment: I am working on this from backend , thanks for answering !

Answer (score 0):

// try this

{
    "buyerId":"ananth",
    "state":"California",
    "mobile_no":"5896235966",
    "permissionType":"3",
    "communityNoArray":["'12'","'123'"],
    "community_name":"abrakasdabrama"
}

Comment: no , not hardcoded values but have to send single quotes inside array.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should create a string from your JSON object. Try with this code:

```
 func jsonToString(json: AnyObject) -> String{
    do {
        let data1 =  try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted)
        let convertedString = String(data: data1, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        return convertedString!
    } catch let myJSONError {
        print(myJSONError)
        return ""
    }
}

let jsonData = [
        "buyerId":"ananth",
        "state":"California",
        "mobile_no": "5896235966",
        "permissionType": "3",
        "communityNoArray": "['1441','1643']",
        "community_name": "abrakasdabrama",
        ] as [String : Any]
```

Then you can call it like

`let messageString = jsonToString(json: jsonData as AnyObject)`

After this, you can send it like a string.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your param in to Json string by using following method

```
func convertToJsonString(from object: Any) -> String? {
        if let objectData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: object, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions(rawValue: 0)) {
            let objectString = String(data: objectData, encoding: .utf8)
            return objectString
        }

      return nil
 }
```